# Trouble getting the Payment Intent from the Expo React Native Stripe API

Tags: react-native, expo, stripe-payments

Hello I have a question concerning the React Native Stripe API from expo. Im having issues getting the payment intent from the CardField Element. I need to create a stripe payment intent to send to our api. I have installed the `@stripe/stripe-react-native` library from expo, and am using the provided CardField element.

[Image of my CardField Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qm9wk.png)

I made my own button for the event handler, since the CardElement does not have one.

[Image of my current event handler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdDxS.png)

I have this useStripe hook but I am unsure of which function to use for getting the payment intent.

[Image of the `useStripe()` hook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3ATs.png)

Could someone point me to the right documentation for accomplishing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CardField` component doesn't create or store PaymentIntents. All it does is collect card details which are then used to confirm PaymentIntents. The PaymentIntent would be created by you separately.

Here's an example of how it works: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/blob/master/example/src/screens/WebhookPaymentScreen.tsx

Notice how when `handlePayPress` is called, a request is made to your server to create a PaymentIntent and the client secret is returned. Then the PaymentIntent is confirmed with the client secret.

Comment: That’s very different from how it’s done in React then? 

The React Stripe Elements create the payment intent, then we send that payment intent Id to our API which then finalizes payment. 

So mobile has to finalize a payment intent? What do I save to my database? The same paymentIntentId as we do from our React web application?”

Comment: React Stripe Elements doesn't create a PaymentIntent either. PaymentIntents can only be created on the server with a secret API key. What you save to your database depends on what information you're interested in.